# Move up floating action button

Tags: dart, flutter

I am adding animated icons in my floating action button at bottom navigation bar. But after adding 2 buttons my FAB moved down.

I am using following code

```
Widget _buildCenterTab(){
    return new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: new List.generate(icons.length, (int index) {
        Widget child = new Container(
          height: 56.0,
          width: 56.0,
          alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
          child: new ScaleTransition(
            scale: new CurvedAnimation(
              parent: _controller,
              curve: new Interval(
                  0.0,
                  1.0 - index / icons.length / 2.0,
                  curve: Curves.easeOut
              ),
            ),
            child: new FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              backgroundColor: blueColor,
              mini: true,
              child: new Icon(icons[index], color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        );
        return child;
      }).toList()..add(
        new FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: null,
          child: new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return new Transform(
                transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(_controller.value * 0.5 * math.pi),
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                child: new Icon(
                    _controller.isDismissed
                        ? Icons.add
                        : Icons.close),
              );
            },
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_controller.isDismissed) {
              _controller.forward();
            } else {
              _controller.reverse();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is screenshot of my problem:
[image]

Comment: can u wrap other two floating buttons inside TransformWidget and animate the position of buttons using  Matrix4.translationValues to corresponding height relative to the main FabbarButton or share the full source code with in some gist

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: Could you Please share gist of your code so a solution could be proposed

Answer (score 3):

One way to get around this would be to create your own `FloatingActionButtonLocation`

```
class _CustomCenterDockedFloatingActionButtonLocation extends FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  const _CustomCenterDockedFloatingActionButtonLocation();

  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    final double fabX = (scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width - scaffoldGeometry.floatingActionButtonSize.width) / 2.0;
    return Offset(fabX, getDockedY(scaffoldGeometry));
  }

  double getDockedY(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    final double contentBottom = scaffoldGeometry.contentBottom;
    final double bottomSheetHeight = scaffoldGeometry.bottomSheetSize.height;
    final double fabHeight = scaffoldGeometry.floatingActionButtonSize.height;
    final double snackBarHeight = scaffoldGeometry.snackBarSize.height;

    double fabY = contentBottom - fabHeight / 2.0;
    // The FAB should sit with a margin between it and the snack bar.
    if (snackBarHeight > 0.0)
      fabY = math.min(fabY, contentBottom - snackBarHeight - fabHeight - kFloatingActionButtonMargin);
    // The FAB should sit with its center in front of the top of the bottom sheet.
    if (bottomSheetHeight > 0.0)
      fabY = math.min(fabY, contentBottom - bottomSheetHeight - fabHeight / 2.0);

    final double maxFabY = scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height - fabHeight;
    return math.min(maxFabY, fabY);
  }
}
```

This is using the same code as `FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked` taken from [the source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1e78c47bc4087dab56d013d594a68794de4c3856/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/floating_action_button_location.dart#L256) and then you can use it in a Scaffold like so:

```
Scaffold(
    body: Container(),
    floatingActionButton: _buildCenterTab(),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: _CustomCenterDockedFloatingActionButtonLocation(),
    ...
);
```

Comment: I've copied this straight from the Flutter source code so it will work exactly the same as the current FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked code, you'll need to have a play around with the code yourself to make it fit your needs.

Comment: The answer is gold. Thank you for this great contribution!

Answer (score 0):

check this code you can wrap your entire column with a container and using transform property to shift it up by 56/2 to center dock it.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() {
    return new HomeScreenState();
  }
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  List<IconData> icons = [(Icons.add),(Icons.clear),(Icons.forward)];
  AnimationController _controller ;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.map),
                title: Text("Hi")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon:Icon(Icons.image),
              title:Text("There"),
            )
          ]
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        width: 56.0,
        height: 56.0*4,
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -56/2, 0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: new List.generate(icons.length, (int index) {
            Widget child = new Container(
              height: 56.0,
              width: 56.0,
              alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
              child: new ScaleTransition(
                scale: new CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: _controller,
                  curve: new Interval(
                      0.0,
                      1.0 - index / icons.length / 2.0,
                      curve: Curves.easeOut
                  ),
                ),
                child: new FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: null,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  mini: true,
                  child: new Icon(icons[index], color: Colors.white),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            );
            return child;
          }).toList()..add(
            new FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return new Transform(
                    transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(_controller.value * 0.5 * math.pi),
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child: new Icon(
                        _controller.isDismissed
                            ? Icons.add
                            : Icons.close),
                  );
                },
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_controller.isDismissed) {
                  _controller.forward();
                } else {
                  _controller.reverse();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This also not helping me. It does only notch design change.

Comment: if you want to implement this behavior you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894449/notch-in-bottomappbar-for-custom-fab/53722628#53722628 you can check this repository to get an idea how it is implemented https://github.com/tiagojencmartins/unicornspeeddial