# Flutter: Undock the FAB in BottomSheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have read the flutter documentations and I have a specific widget behavior I need to implement. However I wasn't able to reproduce it. I would like to undock the floating action button in the bottom sheet. I thought it would be easy with the use of

`floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,`

Unfortunately it only works on the `BottomNavigationBar` not in the `BottomSheet`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('loc'),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet((BuildContext context){
            return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

But my expected result should be the FAB is undocked/floating in the bottom sheet instead of being docked. I don't want to overwork myself for this behavior by making my own implementation of bottom sheet or via gesture widget as much as possible. But if its really necessary I would like some advice or answer in this regards. Thank you and advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the widget behavior I wanted. Please refer to the answer in this post. The answer has opened up a lot of new ideas and other flexible implementations.

[Move up floating action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002977/move-up-floating-action-button)

Closing the issue.